# In DPI-C, How to map data type to reg or wire

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I am writing a CRC16 function in C to use in System Verilog.

Requirement as below:

Output of CRC16 has 16 bits
Input of CRC16 has bigger than 72 bits
The difficulty is that I don't know whether DPI-C can support map data type with reg/wire in System Verilog to C or not ?
how many maximum length of reg/wire can support to use DPI-C.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Stay with compatible types across the language boundaries. For output use `shortint` For input, use an array of `byte` in SystemVerilog which maps to array of `char` in C.

Comment: Hi Dave, Serge,

Thank you very much for your guide.
Now, It works for me.
I try with both svLogicVecVal* and array as input.
Because the C function of CRC16 use "for loop" each byte so using array is better.

Answer (score 0):

Dpi support has provision for any bit width, converting packed arrays into c-arrays. The question is: what are you going to do with 72-bit data at c side?

But, *svBitVecVal* for two-state bits and *svLogicVecVal* for four-stat logics could be used at 'c' side to retrieve values. Look at **H.7.6/7** of lrm for more info.

Here is an example from lrm H.10.2 for 4-state data (logic):

SystemVerilog:

```
typedef struct {int x; int y;} pair;
import "DPI-C" function void f1(input int i1, pair i2, output logic [63:0] o3);
```

C:

```
void f1(const int i1, const pair *i2, svLogicVecVal* o3)
{
  int tab[8];
  printf("%d\n", i1);
  o3[0].aval = i2->x;
  o3[0].bval = 0;
  o3[1].aval = i2->y;
  o3[1].b = 0;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge,

Thank you very much for your solution.
I have tried with svLogicVecVal*. C function and system verilog fucntion can compile without any error. But the C function of CRC16 use "for loop" each byte so using array is better. For other function, I think using svLogicVecVal* is a good choice.